# Handling NameErrors caused by invalid parameters in Python functions

Tags: python, function, error-handling, parameter-passing, nameerror

So I've declared a function with parameters that take arguments, like so;
`def getNumber(number = None, minimum = None, maximum = None):`, but I don't know how to catch and handle NameErrors that arise when the user passes invalid parameters into them.

For example, the user calls the function like `getNumber(apples)`. apples is just a placeholder, the user could enter any non-string/non-number. Note that the word apples isn't a string. When the code is run, it outputs: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
getNumber(apples)
NameError: name 'apples' is not defined
```

How would I go about catching and handling the NameError that occurs?

Comment: Why would *you* do anything about that? It's *their* code that's faulty.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm still being docked marks for it for some reason

Comment: Sounds wrong, you might want to tell us more about what you're doing.

Comment: The function takes in a number the user inputs (assigned to the "number" parameter), and two optional arguments for minimum and maximum size. after checking that the number is within the range, it converts it to an integer and returns it

Comment: Main thing here is: You want to catch an error before you even reach any code you have written. You can't.

Comment: I don't understand what and why you try to do. If you run `apple` without `getNumber()` then you also get the same error. So this error has nothing to do with your function. Error raises before your function is used - you can't stop it. And if someone will use wrong variable with your function then it is his problem, not yours. You may only create better documentation for your code so other would read it before he use your function in his code. You may put it even as docstring in function so others could do `help(getNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the variables like apple that are not defined use something like below:

```
>>> def getNumber(number = None, minimum = None, maximum = None):
...     pass
...
>>>
>>> try:
...     getNumber(apples)
... except NameError as e:
...     print("ERROR {}. Please use proper variable.".format(e))
...
ERROR name 'apples' is not defined. Please use proper variable.
```

Comment: What do you want to do after catching the error? @Roden2019

Comment: Just send an error message telling them to use proper values and loop the function

Comment: @Roden2019 I added a complete working example from python interpreter.

Comment: @Roden2019 If this function is called inside a loop and you want that loop to be continued even after the error you should use **continue** statement inside the except block.

Answer (score 0):

while calling the function, call it like this

```
try:
    getNumber(number, minimum, maximum)
except:
    print("Please pass in valid arguments")
```

If the argument given is not valid or incorrect, it will print out the statment which is written in the `except:` block

Comment: can you share the code that you have written